# Tag a photo with static text using facebook graph api

Tags: iphone

How to tag a photo with static text using facebook graph api ? I have tried lot but could not get a respective answer yet.

I have tagging with userid its work fine.I want to tag a photo with static text.Is it posssible ?

Thanks in advance.............

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Graph API docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/), photos on Facebook have no pure text tags. The only object you can tag to a photo is a Facebook user.